# UWP Listview works strange on mobile

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

[image: ListView with blocks]

I have a ListView where items are TextBoxes(pic.1). In desktop app when I click on any block I can write text and scroll of ListView will stay on current position. But! If I run the app on mobile and click on any box the scroll will return at START position! Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried this ? `MyListView?.ScrollIntoView(MyListView.Items[MyListView.SelectedIndex], ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);`

Comment: Hello, I can't use SelectedIndex because when I click on TextBox SelectionChanged isn't call. But I add your code(SelectedItem -> sender) in GotFocus event on TextBox and scroll anyway move to the first block in my list (on mobile only!)...

Comment: ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" that's answer. It's strange because on desktop ListView scroll was working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" that's answer. It's strange because on desktop ListView scroll was working correctly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).